# Windows IoT Core Headless audio app

Tags: c#, audio, windows-10-iot-core

I'm trying to create headless app for Windows IoT Core on Raspberry Pi 2 which allows to play audio from background task.
Usually, I would create Media Element in UI, but for this purpose I have only background task.

When I use  and following code to play new audio

```
Windows.Media.Playback.BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SetUriSource(new System.Uri("http://stream.funradio.sk:8000/fun128.mp3"));
```

Exception with "Access violation message" is thrown. Also, I tried to create regular background task with audio type declared, but than debugger returns following exception:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in InternetRadioHeadless.winmd

Is there any workaround how to play and control background audio without MediaElement in UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background task need to handle OnCanceled event and shutdown BackgroundMediaPlayer!

```
// Event may raise immediately before continung thread excecution so must be at the end
taskInstance.Canceled += new BackgroundTaskCanceledEventHandler(OnCanceled);

private void OnCanceled(IBackgroundTaskInstance sender, BackgroundTaskCancellationReason reason)
{
    try
    {
        // Shutdown media pipeline
        BackgroundMediaPlayer.Shutdown();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }

    deferral.Complete(); // signals task completion. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to declare the Audio as your background task type as shown in the below pic

[image]